# Custom InfoWindow only showing last element of list in android

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

```
public void marker1(final List<String> listName,
        final List<String> listIllness, final List<String> listIC,
        final List<String> listElderlyimage, List<String> listArduinomac,
        List<String> listLat, List<String> listLong) {


    Log.e("", Integer.toString(listName.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < listName.size(); i++) {
        name = listName.get(i);
        ic = listIC.get(i);
        illness = listIllness.get(i);
        Double Lat = Double.parseDouble(listLat.get(i));
        Double Long = Double.parseDouble(listLong.get(i));
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Lat,
                Long));

        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));


        infoWindowAdapter = new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter();
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(infoWindowAdapter);
        infoWindowAdapter.setName(name);
        infoWindowAdapter.setIC(ic);
        infoWindowAdapter.setIllness(illness);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);


    }// for loop

}// marker1
```

This is the custom infowindowadapter that i use

```
class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private View inflatedView;
    private String name, ic, illness;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setIC(String ic) {
        this.ic = ic;
    }

    public void setIllness(String illness) {
        this.illness = illness;
    }

    MarkerInfoWindowAdapter() {
        inflatedView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);

    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        setInfo(marker, inflatedView);
        return inflatedView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        setInfo(marker, inflatedView);
        return inflatedView;
    }

    private void setInfo(Marker marker, View view) {
        TextView txtname = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txtPatientName);
        TextView txtIC = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtIC);
        TextView txtIllness = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtIllness);
        txtname.setText(name);
        txtIC.setText(ic);
        txtIllness.setText(illness);
        Log.e("<>", txtname.toString());
    }
}
```

Hi there, i am not sure why whenever i click on the marker, it keeps on showing the same person information. I am not sure where went wrong. Please help me! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it keeps on showing the same person information

That is because you only have one "person information" in the `MarkerInfoWindowAdapter`, and you are ignoring the `Marker` that is passed into `getInfoWindow()`. If you want to populate the info window based on the `Marker`, you need to look up the information associated with that `Marker`. [This sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Models) shows looking up your model data based on the `Marker` ID.

Also, do not implement both `getInfoWindow()` and `getInfoContents()`. Only one will be used -- `getInfoWindow()` if it returns a non-`null` value, otherwise `getInfoContents()`. In this case, as you are always returning a non-`null` value from `getInfoWindow()`, `getInfoContents()` will never be called.

Also, do not create an `InfoWindowAdapter` for each `Marker`. Only one `InfoWindowAdapter` is used. In your case, it will be the last one that you create.

Comment: So can I have a list of the marker ? And pass them into the custom info window?

Comment: @MarcusKoh: The `InfoWindowAdapter` needs a way to find the details to show based upon the `Marker` supplied to `getInfoWindow()` or `getInfoContents()`. How you implement that is up to you.